# Binary Search Tree: Issue with Insert Function

Tags: c++, pointers, insert, binary-search-tree

I've been researching how to create binary search trees and i have run into a problem when trying to create my own. I have to use the following private structure to create the tree. Every example that i have looked at uses left and right pointers pointing to the structure and i have to use left and right pointers pointing to my template class. I have been trying to figure out how to write the insert function for adding a new node into my tree but i keep running into problems because of the way these two pointers are setup. Does anyone have a clue on how to make it work with these two pointers below?

```
private:
struct BinaryNode
{
    Comparable element;
    BinarySearchTree<Comparable> *left;
    BinarySearchTree<Comparable> *right;
};
 BinaryNode *root;
};
```

This is my constructor

```
BinarySearchTree<Comparable>::BinarySearchTree() {
BinaryNode *temp;
temp = new BinaryNode;

temp->left= NULL;
temp->right= NULL;

root = temp;
}
```

Comment: Does it help at all to suggest that creating a new node is pointless *until you have data to insert* ?? I.e. your tree's root pointer should be `nullptr` when it is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
public:
    template <typename Comparable>
    void insert(const Comparable& key)
    {
        root = insert(root, key);
    }

private:
    template <typename Comparable>
    BinaryNode* insert(BinaryNode*& current_node, const Comparable& key)
    {
        if (current_node == nullptr)
        {
            // Create a leaf node and return it, thus attaching
            // it to the node we last called the function with

            return new BinaryNode{key, nullptr, nullptr};
        }

        if (key == current_node->element)
            // duplicate element, take some action
        else if (key < current_node->element)
            current_node->left = insert(current_node->left, key);
        else
            current_node->right = insert(current_node->right, key);

        return current_node;
    }
```

Comment: You need to change `insert(BinaryNode*` to `insert(BinaryNode*&` or else this won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your code looks like it would work fine but the problem is that you are passing a pointer to a node in the insert function. I would assume that i have to pass root as that pointer whenever i am calling the insert function right? Well root is in my private section of my class so how will i access it to call this function initially?

Comment: @James Take a look at the function I defined within a `public` label: that's the one your users will use, and it will delegate to the one defined in a `private` section. You simply say `my_tree.insert(45)` and everything gets done.